# Flutter Version Solving Failed-- user_model

Tags: flutter

I got this error message and i'm not sure how to resolve it, please help me below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Brtk.png)

and here's my pubspec.yaml:

```
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.5 <3.0.0"


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  dropdown_search: ^5.0.3
  user_model: any
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  dio: ^4.0.6

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: could you please share your pubspec.yaml file

Comment: okay, i already updated and show my pubspec too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no user_model dependency in pub.dev that's why the error occurs

Comment: well, thankyou so much for this information, i finally know the problems, thankyou